# Java.lang.NullPointerException at getapplicationContext() Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-context

I'm getting NPE when I try to instantiate a class, I already tried using NameOftheClass.this, getApplicationContext(), getApplication(). None of those is working, here is the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.FragmentClientes.<init>(FragmentClientes.java:87)
```

line 87 is:  `mRepositorio = new Repositorio(FragmentClientes.this);`

And here is the snippet:

```
public class FragmentClientes extends ActionBarActivity {


    private boolean searchCheck;
    private List<ClienteModel> clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView lv;
    private ClientViewAdapter ad;
    private ClientViewAdapter ads;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private LinearLayout footerLinearLayout;
    private boolean shouldExecuteOnResume;
    private Repositorio mRepositorio;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_cliente);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        SecurePreferences mSessao = new SecurePreferences(FragmentClientes.this, "sessao");
        mSessao.put("menuAtual", "Clientes");

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaClientes);

    }


    public FragmentClientes(Integer idViagem)  {

        clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();


        try {

            mRepositorio = new Repositorio(FragmentClientes.this);

            List lista = mRepositorio.getClientesViagem(idViagem);

            clientes = lista;


            ad = new ClientViewAdapter(FragmentClientes.this, this, clientes);



            lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);


            lv.setAdapter(ad);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: use SecurePreferences mSessao = new SecurePreferences(FragmentClientes.this, "sessao");

Comment: @AmrutBidri tried that, still getting the same error

Comment: @Stacktwo you will find the complete solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use an activity context inside its constructor, it will now work. Please put all the code from the constructor into a method and call it inside the `onCreate method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_cliente);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    SecurePreferences mSessao = new SecurePreferences(FragmentClientes.this, "sessao");
    mSessao.put("menuAtual", "Clientes");

    Integer idViagem = getIntent().getIntExtra(TAG, -1);

    init(idViagem);



}


public void init(Integer mId)  {

    clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();


    try {

        mRepositorio = new Repositorio(FragmentClientes.this);

        List lista = mRepositorio.getClientesViagem(mId);

        clientes = lista;


        ad = new ClientViewAdapter(FragmentClientes.this, this, clientes);



        lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);


        lv.setAdapter(ad);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Also, you will need to find another way of passing the integer parameter.

For this, use `Intent.putExtra(TAG, idViagem)` on the intent which starts the activity and then retrieve the value in the constructor with `getIntent().getIntExtra(TAG, -1)`

For example if you're starting FragmentClientes activity from another activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FragmentClientes.class);
intent.putExtra("idViagem", int_value_of_id_that_you_passed_through_constructor);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont create Parameteriged `Activity` Constructor

just init your data in `Activity` Call back methods like `onCreate()`,`onResume()`

Start your `Activity` Using `Intent`

For more read Activity doc [Activity Documnetation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

FragmentClientes is an Activity. You should not define a custom counstructor, since the method `onCreate` behaves as constructor and will be called automatically by the system.

so put you code into `onCreate` method.

**Important: you should never, i mean realy never call** `new FragmentClientes(1);`

Comment: I need to pass an Id parameter in the FragmentClientes class, how can I do that without create a constructor?

Comment: Please see my answer for this.

Comment: @Stacktwo i see your problem. You should pass parameters between activities by using Intent extras: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: Another way of data passing between Activities is to use LocalBroadcast.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because yout ListView is not properly instantiated

```
private ListView lv;
```

You never asign (in the code you provided) any instantiation for the object.

Comment: I've updated the question, Still getting the same error

Comment: But your Line (87) shouldn't throw a NullPointerException.  Are you sure is that the Line and not the following one?